# When is the primary UID passed as foreign key?

Tags: database, oracle

I'm afraid my question may be phrased a little inacurately as I'm just starting with databases but I'll try my best... So at my uni, we're using Oracle Data Modeler to model the databases. Question is: when is a primary UID of one entity passed as the foreign key to another entity? From what I (experimentally as I couldn't google it out...) found out, two entities exchange their PK's when they're bound 1:1 - but what about the other types of bindings? Does it matter for the key passing which side is marked optional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to study about different types of relationships and their mapping.

From what little knowledge I have, here are the three types of relationships:

1. **One-to-one**

   This is the relationship where one row of a table is related to zero or one row of the other table. Ideally, this relationship should not be implemented in two different tables. Only one table is sufficient.
   E.g. - Consider we have `person` and `permanent_address`  tables. There can be only one permanent address for a person as per the business rules, we assume. So, we can have:

   ```
   person(personid, firstname, lastname, ...)
   permanent_address (permanent_addressid, personid, line1, line2, ...)
   ```

   where the `personid` in `permanent_address` table refers to `personid` column of `person` table.

   If you want to make the foreign key compulsary, you can add a `NOT NULL` constraint to the column.
2. **Many-to_one**

   This is the more general and widely used sort of relationship where many rows in one table are related to one row in the other table.

   E.g., if you have a business rule wherein a single person can own multiple cars, you have:

   ```
   person(person_id, first_name, last_name, birthdate, ...)
   car (licence_plate_number, person_id, carname, ...)
   ```

   where `person_id` in `car` table refers to the `person_id` in `person` table.
3. **Many-to-many**

   This is the sort of relationship where many rows in one table can be related to zero, one or more rows in the other table.

   E.g., one person can have many hobbies. One hobby can be shared by many people. Hence, we can implement this relationship as follows:

   ```
   person (person_id, first_name, last_name, birthdate, ....)
   hobby (hobby_id, hobby_name, hobby_type, ...)
   person_hobby (person_id, hobby_id)
   ```

   where `person_id` in `person_hobby` table refers to `person_id` of `person` table and `hobby_id` in `person_hobby` table refers to `hobby_id` of `hobby` table. This intermediate table is necessary to implement this many-to-many relationship. We can enforce a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint on the column set (person_id, hobby_id) as a composite primary key in order to avoid assigning the same person the same hobby multiple times.